# stream - Follow activity is shown in news feed

Tags: getstream-io

I have created the following feeds:
notification, timeline_aggregated, user, and timeline.

In my application, users can create posts and follow other users. Users view the posts from people that they follow. However, when I retrieve an individual user's news feed, follow actions are included along with post actions. I've spent a lot of time attempting to figure out why this is. Possibly I am missing something?

Thanks.

```
class AppBaseModel(models.Model):
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True)
  deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

  class Meta:
      abstract = True

class UserFollow(AppBaseModel, Activity):

  class Meta:
      verbose_name = 'UserFollow'
      verbose_name_plural = 'UserFollows'

  user = models.ForeignKey(API_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,   related_name='following_set')
  target_user = models.ForeignKey(API_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='follower_set')

  @property
  def activity_actor_attr(self):
      return self.user

  @property
  def activity_notify(self):
      return [feed_manager.get_notification_feed(self.target_user.id)]

  @property
  def extra_activity_data(self):
      return {'user': self.user.id,
            'target_user': self.target_user,
            'created_at': self.created_at}

  @classmethod
  def activity_related_models(cls):
      return ['user', 'target_user']
```

Comment: I am using the stream-django framework.

Comment: can you share your Follow model definition?

Comment: I have added my model definition. @TommasoBarbugli

Answer (score 0):

You're inheriting the Activity model when you create your UserFollow class, it will create 'follow' activities and push them into the stream as well.

https://github.com/GetStream/stream-django#model-integration
"Simply mix in the Activity class on the models you want to publish."

Comment: Follow notifications are being published into a user's activity feed. When a user follows another user they are able to see follow actions of that user.

Example:
User A follows User B. User A gets items in their news feed when User B follows someone else.

How can I avoid this? @iandouglas

Comment: Per the documentation link I provided above, if you remove the `, Activity` mixin from your `UserFollow` class, it should stop publishing that activity.

Comment: I understand that. However, If I remove the Activity mixin I am unable to notify users when they are followed.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand: User A follows User B, User B follows User C and so User A sees that User B is following User C? Let me dig into this some more and I'll correct my answer above if I find anything to help.

Comment: Correct. That is the issue I am dealing with. In each users news feed I only want to retrieve posts users they follow create. @iandouglas

Comment: let me know if you come across anything.